# Confusion about my supposedly valid flag being declined

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I recently saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27311997/1777090), which had one answer at that time.

The answer said:

> I don't knowwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww

It is deleted by a moderator right now, so I am adding snapshot here.

[image]

Obviously, I flagged it. (Within a minute of the user posting the answer. As I was reading and trying to understand the question when the answer was posted.)

But my flag was declined with this reason:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to
>   support it

See this screenshot:

[image]

According to me it *was* spam behavior, and my flag was supposed to be *accepted*. Then why has this happened? Am I missing something in this scenario?

Comment: Don't flag trolling as spam. I've flagged another post by the same user for moderator attention for trolling as it has been posting nothing but nonsense and is wasting everyone's time.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You flagged it as SPAM.

It is not spam.

Sure, it isn't an answer - that's why we have a "it is not an answer" flag reason.

You should flag appropriately, in particular with spam/offensive flag as they can carry additional penalties to users and possibly the entire network they came from. As such, one should be extremely careful when flagging with those flag reasons and be *certain* they are correct.

The moderator acted appropriately by declining an **incorrect flag**. It certainly brought the non answer to their attention, which they then deleted, but as far as the flag is concerned - that was not the correct flag to use.

Comment: Ok Oded.. Got it now. Thanks :)

Comment: The moderator could have disputed it, too, if had been a bit more constructive ...